# why QTcpSocket::readLine() doesn't work in Qt4

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtcpsocket

I am following this sample: http://crpppc19.epfl.ch/doc/qt4-doc-html/html/network-threadedfortuneserver.html

what I need is not just a server which is able to establish connection and send a data to client (this part is ok) but also a server which is able to receive data from client - and this is something what works to me only in Qt5. I am currently doing this in a separate thread I create for every client:

```
while (Connected)
{
    // read line from client if any was received
    QString text(this->tcpSocket->readLine());
    Send("PING");
    if (text != "")
    {
        text.replace("\n", "");
        text.replace("\r", "");
        // this will write to console / debug
        Syslog::Log(text);
    }
}
```

This work perfect in Qt5 and writes the lines provided by client to terminal (I can simply send them using telnet), however when I compile this with Qt4 only the part Send("PING") works, the string returned by readLine() is always ""